# Teams Graph API call to get chats filtered by last modified doesn't return recent chat

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm pulling group chats from teams with the notion being my code remembers the last-run-time and only asks Graph API for chats modified after that time.

In general this works a treat. Calls look something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<guidyteamname>/channels/19:<guidychannel>@thread.skype/messages/delta?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime%20**gt%202020-06-01T*10:27:53*.00Z**
```

So I'd expect all chats back last modified greater than 10:27, so say chats I posted at 11:00. Only it doesn't. If I leave it several hours (or wind back "the greater than" to, say, 05:00) then it works. Consistent with GraphAPI Explorer and my code.

It looks like how ever the filter works is seriously delayed? A few minutes seems reasonable but this is an extended period, and I cannot find documentation suggesting this?

Answer (score 1):

I did a [List channel message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and the created time for a message is shown in GMT time, not my local time zone. So I would suggest you to try with GMT time filter.

Comment: I did think timezone could be an issue, but I'm in GMT myself, and the Z (I believe) 
implies zero UTC offset, and in any case It's not skewed by 1 hour

Here is an extract from the log my scripts creates, the times shown are the same as my wristwatch. Ultimately it's a one a day batch job but good to understand it.

16:36:07           INFO    Looking for chats after 2020-06-01T14:53:24.00Z
16:36:08           INFO    Calling https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/499f7f5f-blah/channels/19:6blah@thread.skype/messages/delta?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime%20gt%202020-06-01T14:53:24.00Z

Comment: @chaplic, If are still facing this issue, can you please share your request id and time stamp. I am not able to reproduce it